# When to use mock and when to use stub with spock?

Tags: grails, spock

I want to understand more this sentence found in Grails documentation:

> If the test is concerned with proving that the test subject interacts with a collaborator in a particular way, use a mock. If the fact that a collaborator behaves in a certain way exposes a particular behavior in the test subject the outcome of that behavior is what you are testing, use a stub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to test how many times some method will be called use **Mock**:

```
2 * yourService.someMethod(*_) // test that someMethod will be called 2 times
```

If no - use **Stub**

Comment: Evgeny is right. For a complete Spock test sample showing the different capabilities of Spock mocks, stubs and spies, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24415828/1082681).

Comment: Yeah Thanks @Evgeny  ..it seems this the right and brief reponse to understand more between mocks and stubs ...this article agree also your response and i think it is greaaat article to inderstand the difference with spock .https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/stubbing-and-mocking-in-java-with-the-spock-testing-framework